# Alternatives for Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Unfortunately today I discovered that Google Checkout isn't available in my country. I' am asking my self what alternative solutions I have to sell my Android applications.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about selling and marketing an application, not programming one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check here for a review of the most-known appstores:

http://www.maximumtech.com/android-app-store-showdown-which-5-contenders-best

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are some choices.

- Amazon Appstore for Android - http://www.amazon.com/appstore
- SlideME - http://slideme.org
- AndroidPIT - http://www.androidpit.com
- Soc.io Mall - http://mall.soc.io
- AppsLib - http://www.appslib.com
- Opera Mobile App Store - http://mobilestore.opera.com
- GetJar - http://www.getjar.com
- YAAM Market - http://yaam.mobi
- OnlyAndroid - http://onlyandroid.mobihand.com
- Handango - http://www.handango.com
- Insyde Market - http://www.insydemarket.com
- Appoke - http://appoke.com
- Aproov - http://www.aproov.com
- AndroidTapp - http://www.androidtapp.com